# Impala - transform columns to rows without using UNION ALL

Tags: sql, impala

I have a table with users and either activity for each week, for example this is the `user_activity` table:

```
userid | wk1 | wk2 | wk3
u1     |  1  |  0  |  1
u2     |  0  |  1  |  0
u3     |  1  |  0  |  1
```

I would like to transform it to:

```
week   | active
wk1    |   2
wk2    |   1
wk3    |   2
```

I can achieve this using UNION ALL like this:

```
SELECT 'wk1' as week,
       SUM( wk1 ) AS active
FROM user_activity
UNION ALL
SELECT 'wk2' as week,
       SUM( wk2 ) AS active
FROM user_activity
UNION ALL
SELECT 'wk3' as week,
       SUM( wk3 ) AS active
FROM user_activity;
```

Is there a way to achieve the same without using UNION ALL?

Thanks!

Edit:
Impala version: 2.6.0

Reason for no UNION ALL: For each `SELECT`, the entire table will be scanned from HDFS. If I have a huge table, this will result in OOM errors.

Comment: Why without UNION ALL?

Comment: Unless you have a table with the values "wk1", "wk2", and "wk3" in different rows, then you need to construct such a table.  `UNION ALL` seems the most likely approach.

Comment: Impala version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve your performance issue.
The table is being scanned only once.
The records are not being duplicated X3.
The UNION ALL is used here only for a single record.

```
select  concat('wk',cast(c.i as string))    as week
       ,case c.i 
            when 1 then wk1 
            when 2 then wk2
            when 3 then wk3
        end                 as active

from   (select  sum(wk1) AS wk1
               ,sum(wk2) AS wk2
               ,sum(wk3) AS wk3 

        from    user_activity
        ) t

        cross join (            select 1 as i
                    union all   select 2 
                    union all   select 3
                    ) c
;
```

---

```
+------+--------+
| week | active |
+------+--------+
| wk1  | 2      |
| wk2  | 1      |
| wk3  | 2      |
+------+--------+
```

Comment: You guys are awesome!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try unpivoting and aggregating. This way the user_activity table will be read only once.

```
select
    w.week,
    sum(case w.week 
        when 'wk1' then wk1
        when 'wk2' then wk2
        when 'wk3' then wk3
    end) active
from user_activity u
cross join (
    select 'wk1' week union all
    select 'wk2' week union all
    select 'wk3' week 
) w group by w.week;
```

Produces:

```
+------+--------+
| week | active |
+------+--------+
| wk1  | 2      |
| wk2  | 1      |
| wk3  | 2      |
+------+--------+
```

It requires only one aggregate instead of three. I am using `UNION ALL` only to build a custom pivot query. I am not using it on the user table.

Comment: Thanks for initiating the thought in a new direction +1

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the trivial "use `UNION`", the problem seems a bit absurd.  But here is one method:

```
with nounionall as (
      select (case row_number() over (order by userid)
                  when 1 then 'wk1'
                  when 2 then 'wk2'
                  when 3 then 'wk3'
              end) as week
      from user_activity ua
      limit 3
     )
select nounionall.week,
       sum(case when nounionall.week = 'wk1' then wk1
                when nounionall.week = 'wk2' then wk2
                when nounionall.week = 'wk3' then wk3
           end) as actives
from nounionall cross join
     user_activity ua
group by nounionall.week
```

Comment: Thanks for initiating the thought in a new direction +1.

Answer (score 0):

How about this very simple solution without any union all:-

```
SELECT [week],active
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(wk1)wk1,SUM(wk2)wk2,SUM(wk3)wk3
    FROM user_activity)pvt
UNPIVOT ([active] FOR [Week] IN  (wk1,wk2,wk3)) unpvt
```

Comment: I don't think Impala support `UNPIVOT` unfortunately. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome any time. :)